# Relating Tables in OLE DB from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, ms-access, connection, ole-db

I have a large registry of about 260,000 records  in microsoft access with data on land quarter sections. This data was to much for ArcGIS 10.2 to handle directly, so I created a Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB connection to the database and added the query table I greated in Access.

Now I want to relate the table with the quarter section feature class (polygons of all the quarter sections). With this, I need to be able to select one or more quarter sections on the feature class and bring up all the related data from my access table.

However, ArcGIS help states that

> Because OLE DB connections do not have an ObjectID field, which is a
>   field maintained by ArcGIS that guarantees a unique ID for each row in
>   the table, you won't be able to perform certain operations in ArcMap.
>   These include selecting the features in the layer on the map in any
>   way, applying a definition query, creating full relates, or editing
>   the attributes. See About ObjectID fields for more information about
>   working with tables that lack Object IDs.

So I cannot relate a table from the OLE connection with ArcGIS due to lack of ObjectID.

Does anyone know a work around or a way to create the ObjectID so I can select related records from my large access dataset based on selected quarter sections on my feature class.

Comment: "Too much for ArcGIS to handle"?  I'd think Access was the weak link in that chain.  In what format are your polygons?  What other attributes are present?  Can you provide a rough database design diagram?

Comment: The Access table mostly consists of fields referencing information about a particular quarter section of land in Alberta. There is a field however that is about 200 characters long with important environmental information for that quarter section. Access can display the 160,000 records of information fine, but if I import it to ArcGIS and start scrolling to the bottom of the table, It will stop displaying data. This is where I thought I need to connect the table with OLE DB. But now I can't use relate with my polygon feature class.

Comment: Is this a "personal geodatabase"?  Even file geodatabases scale to tens of millions of rows, and I've used hundreds of millions of rows in enterprise geodatabases with ArcGIS, so I'm pretty sure it's not ArcGIS that's the problem, and your solution is probably a step backward.  Why not try importing into a file geodatabase, or even into an Express-based geodatabase. then evaluate from there.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I was just loading the access .mdb into ArcGIS. Actually importing that into my file geodatabase is better supported. I am still interested to know if anyone has a work around for relating feature classes to a table connected with an OLE connection.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince the solution seems to be to not use the workaround that you are having a problem with because:

> ... file geodatabases scale to tens of millions of rows, and I've used
>   hundreds of millions of rows in enterprise geodatabases with ArcGIS,
>   so I'm pretty sure it's not ArcGIS that's the problem, and your
>   solution is probably a step backward. Why not try importing into a
>   file geodatabase, or even into an Express-based geodatabase. then
>   evaluate from there.